# Will I get a noticable performance improvement by parallel execution in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have an API which provides the client with a report. This report is generated using a large collection of unsorted data (hundreds of thousands of rows in 20 different tables). I have tried optimizing the code and got about a 40% improvement in timing but it still takes up to 1 minute.

I was researching and came across this code example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def func1():
  print 'func1: starting'
  for i in xrange(10000000): pass
  print 'func1: finishing'

def func2():
  print 'func2: starting'
  for i in xrange(10000000): pass
  print 'func2: finishing'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=func1)
  p1.start()
  p2 = Process(target=func2)
  p2.start()
  p1.join()
  p2.join()
```

And so I thought of maybe splitting the data in 2. The way I am generating the report is user - by - user (`for user in users`). So if I split the `users` array in `N` equal pieces and run the code in parallel, I will theoretically divide the processing time by `N`, right?

Edit:

As promised, I am here to show you the results.
After my research, I concluded that the best pooling method for my case is the `starmap_async` method. Here is the code with which I realized my solution:

```
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
res = pool.starmap_async(generateReportRow, [(user, database, _client_id, _part_id, _range, state_counts, all_rows, days) for user in users]).get()
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

My server has 4 virtualized shared CPU cores which probably has an impact on the following results which are still relatively impressive.

On 3 different reports, I observed the following performance improvements:

1. Report A from 90 seconds to 30 seconds (1/3)
2. Report B from 150 seconds to 80 seconds (roughly 1/2)
3. Report C from 40 seconds to 20 seconds (1/2)

Another thing which I concluded is that report A had the largest data set which lead to the highest performance improvement (3x) which confirms @A_forsteri's statement in their answer.

Comment: If the computation for each user does not depend on the computation for any other user, and you have N CPU cores which can do the N batches in parallel, then sure. There's no details in your question which would allow anyone to say more than that.

Comment: In addition to what @kaya3 said about users not depending on each other and having the cores available, there isn't really way to say if it will for sure be faster or not. There is additional overhead associated with starting up new processes. Sometimes the overhead makes things slower than if you kept in all in one process, and sometimes it ends up being much faster. They only way to know for sure it to try.

Comment: I would expect the overhead to be negligible compared to a running time of a minute, but yes.

Comment: Another source of overhead is data transfer between the main module and subprocesses.  This can be alleviated by using the [shared memory module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) with multiprocessing (requires Python 3.8+).

Comment: Each user takes about half a second to process and they are independent from one another. The server the app runs on has 2 virtualized cores and the CPU is shared.

Comment: Python is a slow language, but you can use some c libraries like e.g. numpy which can speed up many (number specific) operations significantly

Comment: @mama I am more familiar with C anyway. Worst case scenario, I will generate 3 of my reports (the ones that can take up to a few minutes) with c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `multiprocessing` module  does provide true parallelism.
The creation of `Process` objects and inter-process communication may create some overhead, so given `T` original time your parallel processed time will be `(T/N)+x`, where N is the number of Processes and `x` is the overhead. The larger the data, the more negligible `x` is.

On a side note, I'd suggeste looking into [using Pools.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)

The `map` function does the chopping for you.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def gen_report(user):
    #generate report here
    pass

with mp.Pool(initargs=initargs) as report_generator:
            report_generator.map(func = gen_report, iterable=users)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this and report back with detailed analytics about performance improvement. This could be a huge breakthrough in my problem with reports.